# What is the "canonical" way to exit `ssh -N`

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have an SSH session opened solely for port forwarding, so it has `-N` or `-NT` on its command line. I wonder what's the correct way to tell this session to "quit normally". I know hitting C-c (`SIGINT`) kills the client, but the exit code is not zero. I tried the "tilde after newline" escape sequence but it doesn't seem to be recognized. The console just echoes back the tilde and the dot, with no observable behavior of ssh(1).

Also, I cannot find a way to exit `ssh -Nt`. I have to open another terminal session and do something like `killall ssh`.

I'm running OpenSSH 8.6p1.

Answer (score -1):

`killall ssh` is quite canonical - it sends the `SIGTERM` signal which is how you normally tell applications in Unix/Linux to exit.

`kill -l` has a ton of options and among them is e.g. `SIGQUIT` and `SIGINT` which can also be used.

Check this discussion for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit

Or canonical glibc documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

```
$ ssh -N localhost; echo $?
birdie@localhost's password: 
0
```

(in another terminal)

```
$ killall ssh
```

At the end of the day you need to consult with the source code as signals handling is varied between applications. They can't handle only `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` signals for obvious reasons.

Comment: You could even say `killall vim` is quite canonical when a more appropriate answer is `:q`

Comment: Looks like SSH handles SIGTERM and exits with zero. Other signals result in non-zero exit codes. Interesting.